# Can't understand how to sum items price checkout in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the grad_total of a item bases on the price times the quantity?

```
    def grand_total
      grand_total = 0
      line_items.each do |item|
        grand_total += item.quantity * item.phone.price
      end   
      grand_total
    end
```

Comment: This question has no question into it and also not formatted according to the rules.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Please go through guidelines on how to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an active record object with multiple records, you'll want to try something like this.

```
class << self
   def grand_total
     self.phone.price * self.quantity
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you would want to create a class in the db called cart.
This class would have information about the product.

```
create_table "cart", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "quantity", default(1), not null
    t.integer  "user_id"
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

now that we have a cart on this class we can now do something like this:

```
#cart.rb
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  def grand_total
    product.price.to_f * quantity.to_i
  end
end
```